how to manage ng-select in ionic angular bottom margin
Ng-select in ionic angular how to add extra spacing after dropdown panel end of the screen.
when user clicks on the select options end of the screen at that time user does not identify properly this options is last or any more options are available so need to increase the margin after the dropdown panel.

you can use dropdownPosition: 'top' to open it upside.

No, because it not full fill requirement so need to append extra space to bottom.

You can add a class on the last ion-select-option to add padding/margin to the bottom of the options list.
<ion-select-option class="ion-padding-bottom" value="bananas">Bananas</ion-select-option>

If you are rendering the options dynamically, then you can add the class conditionally by checking whether the option is the last item in the list or not.

sorry, i used "ng-select" not "ion-select" so this one is not working for me!!
